# flutter Stream from Cloud Firestore : how to copy data from snapshot to class and print

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, snapshot

I have to stream the data from Cloud Firestore collection. How should I read the data from snapshot, and then print movieCode and movieName using print() function.

```
Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>> streamMovie() async 
{
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movie')
    .snapshots();
    return snapshots;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this way to get the data in printing.

```dart
  void getMessagesTest() async{
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _firestore.collection('school').orderBy('age', descending: true).where('age', isGreaterThan: 17).get();
    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
    print(allData);
  }
```